# CakePHP: Bad format URLs

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, view, action

I'm trying to create a simple `form` in `CakePHP` detached from a `model`, I'm having problems with the generated URL:

I get this: (doesn't work -> paypal lowercase)

```
http://local.dev/integration-cloud/public_html/paypal/checkout
```

Instead of this: (works -> Paypal camel case)

```
http://local.dev/integration-cloud/public_html/Paypal/checkout
```

This is my code:

**Paypal/view.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('action' => 'checkout')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

If I try this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('url' => array('controller' => 'Paypal', 'action' => 'checkout'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

It's work, but I don't want to write on all my views the reference's controller, is there another way to do this?

btw I'm on a Linux server, could be a `case sensitive` problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was a mix up between the [Paypal's plugin](https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-paypal) and the name of my controller `PaypalController`.

```
public $name = 'Paypal';
```

When I call `paypal` (lowercase) CakePHP is trying to call the plugin instead my `PaypalController` class.

```
http://local.dev/integration-cloud/public_html/paypal/checkout
```

So to fix this problem I had to change the name of my controller to `PaypalPaymentProcessor`

Answer (score 2):

cakephp conventions want controller name in url to be lowercase and underscored

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#url-considerations-for-controller-names

It works even with uppercase controller names but you have to set it manually in every form

Comment: If I call this URL http://local.dev/integration-cloud/public_html/paypal/checkout (lowercase) doesn't work to me and is lowercase and underscored as CakePHP wants, don't know why

Comment: yes but the controller must also be plural. If your model is `Paypal` your controller should be `PaypalsController` and your url local.dev/integration-cloud/public_html/paypals/checkout

Comment: I don't have model (don't need it) that because I use `false` as a first parameter in the `create` method

Comment: If you want, you can always create inflection rules for names like this

Comment: @Eagle like? I think you forgot the example, if you could give me some example with my case will be great

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below if you want:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('url' => '/Paypal/checkout')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

But the below one is recommended in CakePHP:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('url' => array('controller' => 'Paypal', 'action' => 'checkout'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

Comment: Where do you find that the second option is the ones that CakePHP recommended?

Comment: Yeah it is recommended to use array(controller  => ... because if the host vary, the link might not work if you use '/Paypal/checkout' kind of url in cakephp